# HTML Wow.js not working (Wrong initializtion or wrong script calls?)

Tags: javascript, html, animate.css, wow.js

I've been trying to implement wow.js into my HTML code but I'm having trouble making it work. Am I missing script loads or loading the wrong scripts? What might I be doing wrong? Maybe I couldn't initiate wow.js the right way? The code is given below, I could've excluded the nav part out since it will not use animations, but I didn't want to cut any code out. The animation is called in the bottom div part.

Thanks for any help in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta hhtp-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Okan Sen</title>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/jpg" href="OKANSENLogoWineRed.jpg">
    
    <!-- ANIMATE CSS LINK (REQUIRED) -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="global.css">

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.3.0/animate.css"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/core@2.4.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- WOW ANIMATION LIB LINK -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wow/1.1.2/wow.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        // WOW INIT
        new WOW().init();

    </script>
        
        
  </head>
    
    <body>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-transparent">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">OKAN</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                  Dropdown
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="d-flex">
              <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <div class="container-fluid bg animated wow zoomIn">
                    
        
      </div>
      <section class="sec1 animated wow zoomIn">
        <h1>LELELELELEL</h1>
      </section>
        

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: First problem is in /3.3.0/animate.css it's css but added as script

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Okay removed that line, I was trying everything to make it work.

The dev console gives this error additionally
Uncaught ReferenceError: WOW is not defined
    at index.html:28.

Line 28 is this: new WOW().init();

Comment: Let me know if the example that I posted is fine for you?

Comment: Another problem that I found is css link for animate https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css

Comment: Is it a broken link?

Comment: No, it dows not work with latest version

Comment: Ahh I see now, gratitude for clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created vary basic working example

```html
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
      href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/animatecss/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wow/1.1.2/wow.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      new WOW().init();
    </script>

  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="wow bounce">
      Content to Reveal Here
    </div>
  </body>
```

**Edit: Your Example**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta hhtp-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Okan Sen</title>

  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/jpg" href="OKANSENLogoWineRed.jpg">

  <!-- ANIMATE CSS LINK (REQUIRED) -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/animatecss/3.5.2/animate.min.css">


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="global.css">

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->

  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/core@2.4.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <!-- WOW ANIMATION LIB LINK -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wow/1.1.2/wow.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    // WOW INIT
    new WOW().init();

  </script>


</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-transparent">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">OKAN</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
        aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
              aria-expanded="false">
              Dropdown
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li>
                <hr class="dropdown-divider">
              </li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="d-flex">
          <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container-fluid bg animated wow zoomIn">


  </div>
  <section class="sec1 animated wow zoomIn">
    <h1>LELELELELEL</h1>
  </section>


</body>

</html>
```

**Edit 2: Some Explanation**
When I looked at the version of animate.css 4.1.1, as per [link it's not compatible](https://github.com/animate-css/animate.css/issues/1084). [and this](https://github.com/animate-css/animate.css/issues/1091)

So I used a bit older version.

Some recommended [AOS for animation](https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/)

> And for your last question, you can use your own styles as long as we
> are not overriding some original styles from animation

Comment: This works! I quickly tested a few other animations which also work fine as well!

Thanks for this. Was I importing incompatible versions of scripts? I'll have 2 quick questions if you would lend me your time a bit more. 1) I wanted to use Bootstrap 5 but this current example uses 4? Would it be fine if I used 5? 2) This current example doesn't use my css, can I also add my css with a new <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="global.css">? Would it work together with bootstrap?

Comment: bootstrap 5 seems to work fine with internal css, and I could add my css on top of it too.  The page looks as it should for now, and with working animations. Thanks a lot again! I cannot upvote since I don't have reps but you helped a lot!

Comment: Glad that I was useful